# How to clear the query string when call $location.path() in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

After login, I use `$location.path('/dashboard')` to open the dashboard page. Angularjs adds the current querystring, so the URL that appears in the browser is **www.myweb.com/dashboard?urlredirect= ....**

How can I use `$location.path` without drag the querystring?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$location.path('value')` only sets the path value of the URL. So to remove the params you would need to change that part of the URL using `$location.search()` like below.

```
$location.search('urlredirect');
```

[According to the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search), listing the param without a value should delete it from the URL.